# Set an offset/limit for "/me/photos" call in Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

This returns an array ordered in anti-chronological order. How do I specify an offset/limit for the query?

```
$photos = $facebook->api('me/photos');
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `paging` item of the response? Isn't it what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is based on the `created_time` parameter check for yourself to validate

`http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fphotos%3Ffields%3Dcreated_time%2Cupdated_time`

The paging property at the end of every JSON response allows you to traverse the set.

```
"paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?fields=created_time\u00252Cupdated_time&value=1&redirect=1&limit=25&since=1341554766", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?fields=created_time\u00252Cupdated_time&value=1&redirect=1&limit=25&until=1311564489"
  }
```

For example to get all the photos,

```
if($user_id) {
    $the_photos = array();

    $your_photos = $facebook->api("me/photos");

    while ($your_photos['data'])
    {
        $the_photos = array_merge( $the_photos, $your_photos['data'] );

        $paging = $your_photos['paging'];
        $next = $paging['next'];

        $query = parse_url($next, PHP_URL_QUERY);
        parse_str($query, $par);

        $your_photos = $facebook->api(
                "me/photos", 'GET', array(
                'limit' => $par['limit'],
                'until'  => $par['until'] ));
    }

    echo count($the_photos);
}
```

If you still don't feel comfortable with this then just switch out and use `offset` and `limit`, they are allowed as paramaters as well. Increment the `offset` parameter with the limit on each traverse.